# Does tensorflow execute independent parts of graph in parallel on same device?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the code using two Multi-Layer Perceptrons

```
#All these are one device
input = tf.some_place_holder
func1 = MLP1(input)
func2 = MLP2(input)
func3 = tf.some_function...(func1,func2)
```

Will tensorflow execute MLP1 and MLP2 in parallel on the same device or do I have to mention it explicitly to do that?

Thanks in advance.